# confusion in trying to find the probability mass function of a rv

Tags: probability

Toss $n$ biased coins with probability $p$ of heads, independetly of each of the others. Each coin which show heads is tossed again. Let $X$ be the number of heads resulting from the second round of tosses. Goal is to find $P(X=k)$.

Now, in my notes, I have that this is the same as throwing all coins twice and then count the number of heads. I don't see how this can be true. For example, consider case of $n=3$. Suppose we throw once and get $HTH$ and we throw again the 2 heads and say we obtain $TH$. in total we have then 3 heads. However, if we were to throw twice the three coins and count the heads, suppose second throw gives $HHH$, then we'd have $5$ heads. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Now, in my notes, I have that this is the same as throwing all coins twice and then count the number of heads.

No, it is the same as throwing all the coins twice and counting the number of *double-heads*.

Thus: Throwing the three coins twice, receiving (HH),(HT),(TH) or (HH)(HT)(TT) and counting that 1 double head, is effectively the same event as thowing three coins, receiving H,H,T then throwing the two heads again, receiving H, T, and then counting that 1 head.

So the probability distribution for $X$, the count of heads among the retoss is $\mathcal{Binomial}(3,1/4)$.